# Sublime Text - add folder to all projects

Tags: sublimetext2, sublimetext, sublimetext3

In Sublime Text, you can add a folder to a project. Is there a way to add a particular folder to all projects, or to have it added to a new project by default?

In my case, I have some base code, and then each project uses that base code **plus** it's own code on top of that. So I want to include the base code folder(s) in every project by default.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unlike plugins, build systems, and snippets, there is no default template for `.sublime-project` files that you could edit to include your base code folder. So, the easiest workaround I could come up with is to create a `Default.sublime-project` file someplace with your base code folder already in it. Then, when you start a new project, you can use **`Project -> Quick Switch Project...`** or **`Project -> Open Recent ->`** to select `Default`, then you can add your project-specific folders along with the already-existing base code folder. Once that's done, just use **`Project -> Save Project As...`** to rename it to something relevant, and `Default` should be ready for the next use.